# SQL Server Profiler Automatic Restart

Tags: sql-server

How to restart the SQL Server Profiler with a specific trace template defined running on a system automatically, if the system is restarted unexpectedly?

Comment: I googled your question and got [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/start-a-trace-automatically-after-connecting-to-a-server-sql-server-profiler) result. Please do your research. If you tried this and it didn't work, ask a more specific question.

Comment: Why aren't you using extended events? These sessions can be easily configured to start on server startup.

Comment: Agree with @MartinSmith here. You would be much better off setting up an Extended Event here; these automatically start when the server's start up 9if you tell them to), use significantly less resources, and put less pressure on the SQL Server Instance.

Comment: @HoneyBadger i'm looking for a solution like using a batch file that can be scheduled on system wake up which will in turn start the trace based on the trace template defined. Is that possible ??

Answer (score 1):

As you want to start the profiler from batch, you can try:

```
profiler /E /S MyServer\MyInstance /T "YourTrace"
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/profiler-utility) for more parameters